# Google app script trigger quotas exceed. I have 1000 google form with their form submit event

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms, quota

I have script that will generate a dynamic google form.

With every google form it has associated one form submit trigger.

But it has limit of 20 triggers.

So I can maximum generate 20 google form.

But I want to generate 1000 google from with form submit trigger.

Please help if anybody has idea.

Comment: Open 50 gmail accounts

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 20 triggers is by user by script.

You could use 50 accounts or you could create 50 projects or any combination of accounts and projects. In order to make a bit easier to handle multiple projects you might use a library to share the most complex parts of your script across all the projects.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

Comment: Which library I can use?

Comment: @HardikBhalgama I don't know if one exists to do what you need. Try to build one.